# Using the result from a function in a new one (plus more)

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following:

1) calculate the amount of the same numbers in the data list. eg : there are three numbers between and including 10 and 20.

2) represent the value for each number range with the same number of '#'. eg: there are 3 numbers between 10 and 20 = ###.

Ideally ending in having the two values represented next to each other.

Unfortunately I really can't figure out step two and any help would really be appreciated.

My code is below:

```
def count_range_in_list(li, min, max):
ctr = 0
for x in li:
    if min <= x <= max:
        ctr += 1
return ctr

def amountOfHashes(count_range_in_list,ctr):
  ctr = count_range_in_list()
  if ctr == 1:
    print ('#')
  elif ctr == 2:
     print ('##')
  elif ctr == 3:
     print ('###')
  elif ctr == 4:
     print ('####')
  elif ctr == 5:
     print ('#####')
  elif ctr == 6:
     print ('######')
  elif ctr == 7:
     print ('#######')
  elif ctr == 8:
     print ('########')
  elif ctr == 9:
     print ('#########')
  elif ctr == 10:
     print ('##########')


data = [90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51]
print(count_range_in_list(data, 0, 10),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 10, 20),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 20, 30),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 30, 40),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 40, 50),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 50, 60),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 60, 70),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 70, 80),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 80, 90),amountOfHashes)
print(count_range_in_list(data, 90, 100),amountOfHashes)
```

Comment: Try `sum(min <= x <= max for x in li)` for the first function and `"#" * number` for the second.

Comment: `result = count_range_in_list(...)` and `amountOfHashes(result)` . Or directly `amountOfHashes(count_range_in_list(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by clearing out some doubts you seem to have.

First, how to use the value of a function inside another one:

1. You don't need to pass the **reference of a method** to another here. What I mean is, in `amountOfHashes(count_range_in_list,ctr)` you can just drop `count_range_in_list` as a parameter, and just define it like `amountOfHashes(ctr)`. Or better yet, use snake case in the method name instead of camel case, so you end up with `amount_of_hashes(ctr)`. Even **if** you had to execute `count_range_in_list` inside `amount_of_hashes`, Python is smart enough to let you do that without having to pass the function reference, since both methods are inside the same file already.
2. And why do you only need `ctr`? Well, `count_range_in_list` already returns a counter, so that's all we need. One parameter, named `ctr`. In doing so, to "use the result from a function in a new one", we could:

```py
def amount_of_hashes(ctr):
  ...

# now, passing the value of count_range_in_list in amount_of_hashes
amount_of_hashes(count_range_in_list(data, 10, 20))
```

You've figured out step 1) quite well already, so we can go to step 2) right away.

In Python it's good to think of iterative processes such as yours dynamically rather than in hard coded ways. That is, creating methods to check the same condition with a tiny difference between them, such as the ones in `amountOfHashes`, can be avoided in this fashion:

```py
# Method name changed for preference. Use the name that best fits you
def counter_hashes(ctr):
  # A '#' for each item in a range with the length of our counter
  if ctr == 0:
    return 'N/A'
  return ''.join(['#' for each in range(ctr)])
```

But as noted by Roland Smith, you can take a string and multiply it by a number - that'll do exactly what you think: repeat the string multiple times.

```py
>>> 3*'#'
###
```

So **you don't even need** my `counter_hashes` above, you can just `ctr*'#'` and that's it. But for consistency, I'll change `counter_hashes` with this new finding:

```py
def counter_hashes(ctr):
  # will still return 'N/A' when ctr = 0
  return ctr*'#' or 'N/A'
```

For organization purposes, since you have a specific need (printing the hashes **and** the hash count) you may then want to format right what comes into `print`, you could make a specific method for the printing, that calls both `counter_hashes` and `count_Range_in_list`, and gives you a cleaner result afterwards:

```py
def hash_range(data, min, max):
  ctr = count_range_in_list(data, min, max)
  hashes = counter_hashes(ctr)
  print(f'{hashes} | {ctr} items in range')
```

The use and output of this would then become:

```py
>>> data = [90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51]
>>> hash_range(data, 0, 10)
N/A | 0 items in range
>>> hash_range(data, 10, 20)
### | 3 items in range
>>> hash_range(data, 20, 30)
#### | 4 items in range
```

And so on. If you just want to print things right away, without the `hash_range` method above, it's simpler but more lengthy/repetitive if you want a oneliner:

```py
>>> ctr = count_range_in_list(data, 10, 20)
>>> print(counter_hashes(ctr), ctr)
### 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do it like this:

Python 3.x:

```
def amount_of_hashes(ctr):

    while ctr > 0:
        print('#', end = '')
        ctr = ctr-1
```

Python 2.x:

```
def amount_of_hashes(ctr):

        while ctr > 0:
            print '#',
            ctr = ctr-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Counting the number in a list can be done like this:

```
def count_range_in_list(li, mini, maxi):
    return len([i for i in li if mini <= i <= maxi])
```

Then making a number of hashes is even simpler. Just multiply a string containing the hash sign with a number.

```
print(ount_range_in_list(data, 0, 10)*'#')
```

Example in IPython:

```
In [1]: data = [90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51]            

In [2]: def count_range_in_list(li, mini, maxi): 
   ...:     return len([i for i in li if mini <= i <= maxi]) 
   ...:                                                                                                  

In [3]: print(count_range_in_list(data, 0, 10)*'#')                                                      


In [4]: print(count_range_in_list(data, 10, 20)*'#')                                                     
###

In [5]: print(count_range_in_list(data, 20, 30)*'#')                                                     
####
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to use a for loop with range:

```
# Most basic
def count_range_in_list(li, min, max):
    ctr = 0
    hashes = ""
    for x in li:
        if min <= x <= max:
            ctr += 1
            hashes += "#"
    print("There are {0} numbers = {1}".format(ctr, hashes))

# more declarative
def count_range_in_list(li, min, max):
    nums = [x for x in li if min <= x <= max]
    hashes = "".join(["#" for n in nums])
    print("There are {0} numbers = {1}".format(len(nums), hashes))
```